# Combining multiple flags of an enum?

Tags: c#, enum-flags

I've been trying to use multiple flags for the SpeechLibs Talk() function.
This is what I am trying to do:

```
V.Speak ("Text", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync + SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFIsXML);
```

However, it gives me following error:

> Error 1   Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags' and 'SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags'  c:\users\max\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\switch\switch\default_tts_screen.cs  62  51  Switch

The documentation though clearly states that this should be possible:

```
Example
The following code snippet demonstrates the Speak method with several   commonly used flag settings.
[...]
V.Speak "text with XML", SVSFIsXML + SVSFlagsAsync
[...]
```

Please note that I am using C#, this however shouldn't change anything. Right?..
Please help me with this problem as it's already been smashing my head into my table since hours now.
I haven't found a solution to this online.

Comment: Flags should be concatenated with the | operator, its binary equivalent to the + but addition operators are not defined for enums.

Comment: Not sure what language your example is in, but the + operator may be equivalent to | when using flags, or its converting them to an integer first and then adding them. You could have done `(SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags)((int)SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync + (int)SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFIsXML)` and it would work the same.

Comment: @RonBeyer C# Flags are not required to only have one bit set, so `+` isn't always equivalent to `|`

Comment: @RoadieRich no, but if they are defined with the [Flags] attribute, they have to be in order to concatenate them correctly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx See the guidelines, second bullet point. Other than combinations, which then yes, + would corrupt what you want to do.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's a guideline, not a requirement. And the third bullet point contradicts that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You combine enum flags with a bitwise OR operator as follows:

```
V.Speak ("Text", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync | SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFIsXML);
```

Comment: This is because you could have multiple flags combined in one enum value.  For instance, you might have `enum Access {Read=1, Write=2, All=3)`  If you set `myAccess = Access.Read`, then later on, you decide you need more access, `myAccess = myAccess + Access.All`, `myAccess` has the unexpected value of `4`.  Using `|`, you get exactly what you want.